# Refreshing another forms datagridview upon button click event of another form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I have a datagridview which displays all the details of a sale. I have another form to perform sale billing. So when i save a bill the item quantity will reduce from database. So When i take form which contains the datagridview of sale details, it should update upon save bill click in billing form.

note that these billing details form and billing form are my child forms. these are contained in menu strip. Iam not creating a new form upon every click in menu strip.. Iam just maximizing the form if it opened once. So when i press list bill details form it just maximizes only.. wont reload to reflect new stock. Any way to reload that form?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer by myself. I should add the 'select * ' query to display billdata in datagridview in Resize event. Hence Solved! :D